# Creating an arbitrary number of pointers in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, image-processing

I want to implement a n*n average filter. For that end, I want to create n*n pointers to point for a n*n square area of the original image and store the value of each component in each pixel of that square. I want to give a distinct name to each pointer, that is, I want to create pointers starting at dataPtrOrigin_aux0 and ending at dataPtrOrigin_aux(n*n-1). I have the following code:

`        internal static void nxn_average(Image img, Image imgUndo){

```
    unsafe
        {

            MIplImage m = img.MIplImage;
            MIplImage mUndo = imgUndo.MIplImage;
            byte* dataPtrFinal = (byte*)m.imageData.ToPointer();
            byte* dataPtrUndo = (byte*)mUndo.imageData.ToPointer();


            int width = img.Width;
            int height = img.Height;
            int nChan = m.nChannels;
            int padding = m.widthStep - m.nChannels * m.width;

            int b_sum, g_sum, r_sum;
            int b_average, g_average, r_average;
            int x, y, i, j, k;
            int counter = 0;
            int n = 5;

            string[] ptr_names_arr = new string[n*n];

            //create the names of the n*n pointers

            for (i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
            {

                char ptr_nr = (char)i;

                string ptr_name = String.Concat("dataPtrOrigin_aux", ptr_nr);

                ptr_names_arr[i] = ptr_name;

            }

            for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {


                    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
                        {


                            string ptr_aux = ptr_names_arr[counter];
                            counter++;

                            byte*  ptr_aux = (byte*)(dataPtrUndo + (y - (int)Math.Floor(n/2) + j) * m.widthStep + (x - (int)Math.Floor(n/2) + k) * m.nChannels);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }`
```

Although, I get an error when I try to use the line:

```
byte*  ptr_aux = (byte*)(dataPtrUndo + (y - (int)Math.Floor(n/2) + j) * m.widthStep + (x - (int)Math.Floor(n/2) + k) * m.nChannels);
```

Is there any other way to create an arbitrary number of pointers?

Comment: Can you please fix your sample so it at least don't have duplicated names in the same scope (`ptr_name`)?

Comment: Is your error that _A local variable named ptr_aux already exists in this scope_?

Comment: Why are you using unsafe rather than managed code for this?

Comment: Yes, it is, and I kind of understand why, but is there any way to force the ptr_aux to be the name of the pointer and not correspond to the variable previously defined?

Comment: @FilipeAleixo, just change the previous _string_ variable to be named something else.